# how to make DIV with responsive image and dynamic text overlay

Tags: html

How to make this background image responsive and have the text stay in a specific placement on the image (as it gets resized) ?

http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Dj7Hb/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="YOUR_IMAGE" />
<div class="content">
    <div>
        <div>
             blahblab
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
}
.wrapper > img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
.content {
top:0;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.content > div {
display:table;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.content > div > div {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your background to a background-image in css with size cover on the wrapper instead of an img tag.

```
background-image: url(your-img);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Hope this helps.